# Can I declare a NULL value in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, null

Just curious, seems when declaring a name, we always specify some valid values, like let a = 3. Question is, in imperative languages include c/java there's always a keyword of "null". Does Haskell has similar thing? When could a function object be null?

Answer (score 14):

There *is* a “null” value that you can use for variables of any type. It's called ⟂ (pronounced *bottom*). We don't need a keyword to produce bottom values; actually ⟂ is the value of any computation which doesn't terminate. For instance,

```
bottom = let x = x in x   -- or simply `bottom = bottom`
```

will infinitely loop. It's obviously not a good idea to do this deliberately, however you can use [`undefined`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:undefined) as a “standard bottom value”. It's perhaps the closest thing Haskell has to Java's `null` keyword.

But you definitely shouldn't/can't use this for most of the applications where Java programmers would grab for `null`.

- Since everything in Haskell is immutable, a value that's undefined will always stay undefined. It's not possible to use this as a “hold on a second, I'll define it later” indication<sup>†</sup>.
- It's not possible to check *whether* a value is bottom or not. For [rather deep theoretical reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), in fact. So you can't use this for values that may or may not be defined.

And you know what? It's really good that Haskell does't allow this! In Java, you constantly need to be wary that values might be null. In Haskell, if a value is bottom then something is plain broken, but this will never be part of intended behaviour / something you might need to check for. If for some value it's *intended* that it might not be defined, then you must always make this explicit by wrapping the type in a [`Maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t:Maybe). By doing this, you make sure that anybody trying to use the value *must* first check whether it's there. Not possible to forget this and run into a null-reference exception at runtime!

And because Haskell is so good at handling variant types, checking the contents of a `Maybe`-wrapped value is really not too cumbersome. You can just do it explicitly with pattern matching,

```
quun :: Int -> String
quun i = case computationWhichMayFail i of
   Just j  -> show j
   Nothing -> "blearg, failed"

computationWhichMayFail :: Int -> Maybe Int
```

or you can use the fact that `Maybe` is a functor. Indeed it is an instance of almost every specific functor class: [`Functor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t:Functor), [`Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative), [`Alternative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative), [`Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#t:Foldable), [`Traversable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#t:Traversable), [`Monad`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Monad), [`MonadPlus`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus). It also lifts [semigroups](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Semigroup-0.0.7/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Semigroup) to [monoids](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Monoid).

### [Dᴏɴ'ᴛ Pᴀɴɪᴄ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) now,

you don't need to know what the heck these things are. But when you've learned what they do, you will be able to write very concise code that automagically handles missing values always in the right way, with zero risk of missing a check.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Because Haskell is lazy, you generally don't need to defer any calculations to be done later. The compiler will automatically see to it that the computation is done *when it's necessary*, and no sooner.</sub>

Comment: Beautiful. For some reason, until this moment I had not meditated on how the inability to check for bottoms means that nobody tries to check for bottoms, and what that means for its parallels to Java's `null`. Thank you for this insight.

Answer (score 11):

There is no null in Haskell. What you want is the `Maybe` monad.

```
data Maybe a
    = Just a
    | Nothing
```

`Nothing` refers to classic null and `Just` contains a value.

You can then pattern match against it:

```
foo Nothing  = Nothing
foo (Just a) = Just (a * 10)
```

Or with `case` syntax:

```
let m = Just 10
 in case m of
      Just v  -> print v
      Nothing -> putStrLn "Sorry, there's no value. :("
```

Or use the supperior functionality provided by the typeclass instances for `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Alternative`, `Monad`, `MonadPlus` and `Foldable`.

This could then look like this:

```
foo :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
foo x y = do
  a <- x
  b <- y
  return $ a + b
```

You can even use the more general signature:

```
foo :: (Monad m, Num a) => m a -> m a -> m a
```

Which makes this function work for ANY data type that is capable of the functionality provided by `Monad`. So you can use `foo` with `(Num a) => Maybe a`, `(Num a) => [a]`, `(Num a) => Either e a` and so on.

Comment: Please [avoid introducing every type which happens to have a `Monad` instance as “the X monad”](http://blog.jle.im/entry/io-monad-considered-harmful), especially to beginners. (And, `Maybe a` is not a monad, `Maybe` is.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout Oh wow cool. I've actually learned something today. :D

Answer (score 8):

Haskell does not have "null". This is a design feature. It completely prevents any possibility of your code crashing due to a null-pointer exception.

If you look at code written in an imperative language, 99% of the code *expects* stuff to never be null, and will malfunction catastrophically if you give it null. But then 1% of the code *does* expect nulls, and *uses* this feature to specify optional arguments or whatever. But you can't easily tell, by looking at the code, which parts are expecting nulls as legal arguments, and which parts aren't. Hopefully it's documented — but don't hold your breath!

In Haskell, there is no null. If that argument is declared as `Customer`, then there *must* be an actual, real `Customer` there. You can't just pass in a null (intentionally or by mistake). So the 99% of the code that is expecting a real `Customer` will always work.

But what about the other 1%? Well, for that we have `Maybe`. But it's an explicit thing; you have to *explicitly* say "this value is optional". And you have to *explicitly* check when you use it. You cannot "forget" to check; it won't compile.

So yes, there is no "null", but there is `Maybe` which is kinda similar, but safer.

Comment: Also note that this is pretty much the motivation for the introduction of [`java.util.Optional<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) in Java 8. It's not the same as `null`, but it solves what is probably the only valid use case for `null` in a much nicer way. If you want to understand Haskell's `Maybe` as a Java developer, `Optional<T>` is a good start.

Comment: @ComicSansMS Indeed. There's also `Nullable<T>` in C#. It exists because `int` variables can't be null, and sometimes you want them to be. In Haskell, *everything* is non-nullable, unless you use `Maybe`.

Comment: I meant to say... Eiffel is an OOP language that allows you to declare variables as "not nullable". (They wanted to make it the default, but that would break backwards compatibility.)

Answer (score 2):

Not in Haskell (or in many other FP languages). If you have some expression of some type `T`, its evaluation will give a value of type `T`, with the following exceptions:

- infinite recursion may make the program "loop forever" and failing to return anything

  ```
  let f n = f (n+1) in f 0
  ```
- runtime errors can abort the program early, e.g.:

  - division by zero, square root of negative, and other numerical errors
  - `head []`, `fromJust Nothing`, and other partial functions used on invalid inputs
  - explicit calls to `undefined`, `error "message"`, or other exception-throwing primitives

Note that even if the above cases might be regarded as "special" values called "bottoms" (the name comes from domain theory), you can not test against these values at runtime, in general. So, these are not at all the same thing as Java's `null`. More precisely, you can't write things like

```
 -- assume f :: Int -> Int
if (f 5) is a division-by-zero or infinite recursion
then 12
else 4
```

Some exceptional values can be caught in the `IO` monad, but forget about that -- exceptions in Haskell are not idiomatic, and roughly only used for IO errors.

If you want an exceptional value which can be tested at run-time, use the `Maybe a` type, as @bash0r already suggested. This type is similar to Scala's `Option[A]` or Java's not-so-much-used `Optional<A>`.

The value is having both a type `T` and type `Maybe T` is to be able to precisely identify which functions always succeed, and which ones can fail. In Haskell the following is frowned upon, for instance:

```
 -- Finds a value in a list. Returns -1 if not present.
 findIndex :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> Int
```

Instead this is preferred:

```
 -- Finds a value in a list. Returns Nothing if not present.
 findIndex :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> Maybe Int
```

The result of the latter is less convenient than the one of the former, since the `Int` must be unwrapped at every call. This is *good*, since in this way each user of the function is prevented to simply "ignore" the not-present case, and write buggy code.